# how to smooth zoom in on a movie clip using transform scale in video sequence editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I've created a transform in the video sequence editor that applies a uniform scale to a strip.

The zoom in happens as soon as the transform frame is reached and then the zoom out happens just as abruptly at the end of the transform.  I would like zoom to be progressive.

How can I do this with blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to do linear interpolation in the graph editor?
Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then <kbd>V</kbd>> *Vector*.

Optionally, after the previous steps: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>> *Linear extrapolation*.

Comment: In the graph editor, I have a single line at 0.0.  All options in the Select menu are greyed out.  The strips in the vse are imported videos, no 3D models exist in my project.

Comment: then you have to simulate objects.
You may try the following:
import images as planes, and import your sequence to a plane
afterwards, you have to match your camera to the image (maybe try BLAM addon so its easier to match dimensions and position)
then, when you want to perform a zoom, you can get your cam closer to the plane with the sequence, by keyframing camera positions. (after this you have keyframes on the graph editor and fine tune them as I explained previously.

Comment: I just remembered, on the video editor, you can keyframe the "transform" node. Then fine tune on the graph editor. It might be easier

Comment: Go to compositor, import your image sequence, connect to a "transform" node, output to composite and viewer node.

then you can keyframe the transform node on "scale". 
To fine tune the transform node, select it and go to graph editor.

Comment: http://software-tips.wonderhowto.com/how-to/pan-zoom-images-with-nodes-blender-379407/

Comment: So sorry, I'm trying to work with movie clips not images.  Useful link though :)

Comment: in compositer:
shift+A, add movie clip-->
connect it to scale node-->
change scale node to scene size-->
connect it to transform node-->
keyframe the scale as needed (and fine tune it in graph editor as needed)-->
connect it to composite and/or viewer node-->
render it

Comment: No, it isn't.  I've just imported a movie clip and that is it.

Comment: it will work with both still images and/or movie clips